# Differentiating between a file and a directory in a Collection

Tags: java, java-io

How will I be able to tell if an element in the string array contains a file or a sub directory?

Each file seams to output the file name and file extension but directories seam to just have a plane name?

```
public static File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Matthew\\Desktop\\X\\");

String[] contents = f.list();
for(String con : contents) {
System.out.println(con);    
}
```

//Output to console

a.txt

b.txt

Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **isFile()** and **isDirctory()** methods. Both has **boolean** as return type. So you can easily determine as per their return values.

For more information about their behaviour you can see [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`listFiles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) which returns `File[]` instead of `list` which returns `String[]`. Then you could use `isDirectory` method:

```
File[] contents = f.listFiles();
for(File con : contents) {
    System.out.println(con.isDirectory());    
}
```